# How to fix java illegalaccessexception in jdk 11

Tags: java, java-11, apache-zeppelin

I have some java application, when I start that application I get the below error

```
caused by: java.lang.illegalaccessexception: class org.apache.lucene.store.mmapdirectory$2$1 cannot access class jdk.internal.ref.cleaner (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.ref to unnamed module @3d97a632
```

it works in jdk1.8, but due to some reason, I can not downgrade.

After searching more cam to know that setting this '**--add-exports java. base/JDK.internal.misc=all-unnamed'** but the application I am using is started by a lot of internal scripts so how to set them at as ENV level so that JVM can pick?

Comment: OS level? this is a VM specific start-up flag (that will not work in jdk-17 anyway)

Comment: I mean set as ENV var so that it can become  default for JVM

Comment: you need to deifne better what do you mean by "I start that application", how do you do that? what is the application based out of?

Comment: This looks like it is because of Java Modules, which were added in Java 9.

Comment: @Naman, application is Zeppelin, there are few scripts file to start the daemon, the script file does steps internally

Comment: @kcoder to start off with, you would have to unfold the magic that those scripts do internally. at some point in time, they would be invoking `java ...`, that's where you would have to make sure your args reach. Anyway, improving question tags, to seek help from people experienced with the application.